# Initialize struct with an empty array

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

> I am trying to initialize this struct and I can't figure out how to pass in a dynamically sized empty array..

```
      uint8[] id;
  users[msg.sender] = User( true, msg.sender, _username, block.timestamp, block.number, 0, id, 0);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following will work:

```
contract Test {
    struct Object {
        uint a;
        string b;
        string[] c;
        mapping(uint => uint) d;
    }

    Object field;

    function Test() {
        field = Object({
            a: 1,
            b: "abc",
            c: new string[](0)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I skip it:     Error: Wrong argument count for function call: 7 arguments given but expected 8.

Comment: My bad, it is `mapping` that you skip. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok great that works!